# Does high min degree and high odd girth imply near bipartiteness?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Say $G$ has odd girth at least $k$ and min degree $2n/k$. There is a classical result by Andrasfai, Erdos, and Sos that says that $G$ is bipartite. (Odd girth is the length of the shortest odd cycle in a graph.)

My question is, does this degrade gracefully? For instance, if the min degree is $n/100k$, can one remove some number of nodes or edges to get a bipartite graph?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused. How is a graph bipartite if it has any odd cycle ?

Comment: I think it works for "at least $k$".  There's a bad scan of the paper at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X74901332 .  The relevant claim is "$G$ non-bipartite, odd girth $k > 3$ $\Rightarrow$ $\delta(G) \leq 2n/k$" at the top of page 210.

Comment: The previous comment was in response to @SureshVenkat's query, which also had me wondering.

Comment: @BenBarber You are right, thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you may have to remove a constant fraction of the vertices to obtain a bipartite graph.

Take $k$ stable sets $S_1,\ldots,S_{k}$ of size $n/k$, with $k$ odd, and for any $i$, put a random bipartite graph between $S_i$ and $S_{i+1}$ (indices modulo $n/k$), with density 1/100. The expected degree of a vertex is $n/50k$ and with high probability the minimum degree is more than $n/100k$. The odd girth is k. Now, how many vertices do we need to remove to obtain a bipartite graph? Well if we leave a constant fraction of vertices in each of the $S_i$'s, there is a cycle of length $k$ with high probability. So we need to remove a constant fraction of the vertices, say $0.9 n/k$.

(On the other hand, in this example by removing a set $S_i$ we obtain a bipartite graph, so in this case we only need to remove $n/k$ vertices to obtain a bipartite graph)

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned that example in the question; I would love a proof that O(n/k) is enough.